# How can I store user details into database after LDAP successful login?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ldap

I'm working on a Spring Boot application and I need to make it secure by adding LDAP authentication.  The authentication process based on LDAPusername/password is working, but I'm having a hard time in getting user data (username, full name, etc.) after a successful login and storing it into a database.

Comment: Can you please tell us a bit more what you mean by " im having hard time in getting user data "

Comment: I DONT KNow what is exactly the correct method to retrieve / recuperate user data

Comment: The first step is to write some code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely save the data of the LDAP user in the db. After successful authentication, you can call your custom class, something like this :

```
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsMapper;

@Service
public class LDAPUserDetailsMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper{}
```

Then you can override the method :

```
@Override
public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
/** your custom logic goes here. Here you can get the user details from ctx, 
and then use the information to store the data in db and then return the user details.**/
}
```